# Openbravo script export.database changes procedure return type

Tags: database, export, openbravo

Script export.database in Openbravo changes the return type of procedures that return RECORD (e.g. m_reservation_reallocate). In the xml:

function name="M_RESERVATION_REALLOCATE" type="NULL"

Are this normal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openbravo's [DB Source Manager](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/DBSourceManager) does not support return type "**RECORD**" You can find out  more about the return types which openbravo supports [click here.](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/PL-SQL_code_rules_to_write_Oracle_and_Postgresql_code#Elements_not_supported_by_dbsource_manager)

You can write your own HQL functions using DAL instead of writing any new functions  that is specific to either postgreSQL or Oracle.